# NAT Loopback (hairpin) not working - OpenWRT

Tags: networking, router, nat, openwrt

I have a home network with a modem and a router (SmartRG SR905AC) provided by my ISP (EBOX). The firmware version of SMART/OS is 10.6.5.1, which is "Powered by OpenWRT", but they don't mention which version.

I also have a SQL server that is accessible from the internet with my public IP. I want my laptop to be able to access that server from both the Internet when I'm not home and from the LAN when I'm home.

I have setup port forwarding as follows:

```
Source Zone: WAN
Destination Zone: LAN
Destination IP: 192.168.1.100 (address of the SQL server)
Public Port: 3306
Protocol: TCP+UDP
Local Port: 3306
Port Type: Port
Enable Hairpin: Yes
```

While I can access the server fine over Internet, I cannot access it when I am on the home network.

Is there anything else I should know that could affect this?

I know that opening a MySQL server to the internet is not safe and I do not want to setup a VPN.

Thank you

Comment: Are you accessing your server by name or IP address?

Comment: I'm trying to access it using the external IP address

Comment: do you have SNAT option in firewall rules?

Comment: I don't see anything called SNAT. I can enable/disable the firewall, stealth mode (?), setup firewall rules, port forwarding, DMZ, NAT-PMP. I may be able to do something like that through firewall rules, but I'm not familiar with the syntax for destination IPs/masks.

Comment: do you have access through ssh? `root` access?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to it via PuTTY

Answer (score 0):

This rule works fine in a router over here running LEDE 17.01.4

```
config redirect
        option target 'DNAT'
        option src 'wan'
        option dest 'lan'
        option proto 'tcp'
        option src_dport '80'
        option dest_ip '192.168.2.199'
        option dest_port '8080'
        option name 'HTTP'
```

Could you check your device for DNAT rule? You will find in `/etc/config/firewall`

**Edit:** LEDE is a fork of Openwrt.